# Magento Community Connect: Not valid config.ini file

Tags: magento-community, magento-connect

We're running Magento Community.

When I navigate to `System > Magento Connect > Magento Connect Manager`, I got a blank screen with a single message:

> Not valid **config.ini** file.

If I open `/downloader/config.ini` with Notepad or Notepad++, I see lots of black `NULL`s.

How can I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced the contents of /download/config.ini with:

> root_channel=community

and the Magento Connect Manager opened successfully.

Perhaps the file got corrupted on upload/download.